# Select 2 jQuery doesn't work in laravel 6

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, laravel-6

So I am trying to create a form where the user can add a book to the database.
I wanted to use the select bars from Select2, which allow the user to search for the select elements. 
I followed a tutorial on how to make this work, but somehow it doesn't seem to work for me.
Any ideas on what I did wrong?

The relevant code:

```
@extends('layout')


@section('title')
<title>Add new book</title>
@section('stylesheets')
<link href="css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/select2.min.js"></script>
@endsection
@section('content')
<style>
    .uper {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
</style>
<div class="card uper">
    <div class="card-header">
        Neues Buch hinzufügen
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('books.store') }}">
            <div class="form-group">
                @csrf

                ...

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="authors">Author(en):</label>
                <select name="authors[]" multiple class="form-control select2-multi <!-- @error('authors') is-invalid @enderror -->">
                    @foreach ($authors as $author)
                    <option value="{{ $author->id }}">{{ $author->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                @error('authors')
                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
            </div>

...

 </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.select2-multi').select2();
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried to use the id of your select element instead of the class `$('#MySelect').select2();`

Comment: Yes, that does not work either

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
select2.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
create:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at create:16
select2.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the code as is, your script tag is outside of your sections, thus not getting read inside the file, move it inside any section really, but in this cas the `stylesheets` would be more appropriate.

```
@section('stylesheets')
<link href="css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.select2-multi').select2();
</script>
@endsection
```

While we're at it, your `title` section doesn't have an `endsection`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried doing that and unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: @mekol what is your console saying?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
select2.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
create:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at create:16
select2.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @mekol where are your css and js stored ? In your public folder ? Try replacing your href and src with assets, like this : `{{ asset('css/select2.min.css') }}` and `{{ asset('js/select2.min.js') }}`

Comment: Two of the error messages disappeared, but I am still getting 
create:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at create:3
(anonymous) @ create:3
select2.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at select2.min.js:2
    at select2.min.js:2

Comment: You need to add jquery too, please search for answers on the web before asking.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't wanna seem dumb, I have searched the web for a long time. This is my first time making an application and I'm kind of struggling. I have included the jQuery as well, but it is still not working.

Comment: "it is still not working" is not enough to be able to help you, details are key, and no question is dumb if the necessary search for the answer is done before asking.